glmer significant and post-hoc test not significant
I ran a glmer model to test the effects of treatment on my response variable
summary(model1)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(Numero_foglie_minate, Foglie_sane) ~ Trattamento + Blocco +      Data_rilievo + (1 | ID_pianta)
   Data: data_infestate
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4066.1   4142.5  -2020.0   4040.1     2632 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6876 -0.4813 -0.3308  0.1900  4.8004 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID_pianta (Intercept) 1.307    1.143   
Number of obs: 2645, groups:  ID_pianta, 478

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          -2.98258    0.18485 -16.135  < 2e-16 ***
TrattamentoLavanda   -0.43253    0.19116  -2.263   0.0237 *  
TrattamentoRosmarino -0.40539    0.20355  -1.992   0.0464 *  
TrattamentoTimo      -0.22146    0.18686  -1.185   0.2360    
Blocco2              -0.33824    0.17387  -1.945   0.0517 .  
Blocco3              -0.04463    0.17187  -0.260   0.7951    
Data_rilievo16       -0.01192    0.12264  -0.097   0.9226    
Data_rilievo22        0.08879    0.12123   0.732   0.4639    
Data_rilievo29       -0.03263    0.12380  -0.264   0.7921    
Data_rilievo36       -0.32984    0.12850  -2.567   0.0103 *  
Data_rilievo52       -0.56837    0.12778  -4.448 8.67e-06 ***
Data_rilievo9         0.03357    0.12290   0.273   0.7848    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TrttmL TrttmR TrttmT Blocc2 Blocc3 Dt_r16 Dt_r22 Dt_r29 Dt_r36 Dt_r52
TrttmntLvnd -0.468                                                                      
TrttmntRsmr -0.411  0.463                                                               
TrattamntTm -0.512  0.495  0.463                                                        
Blocco2     -0.441 -0.034 -0.127  0.018                                                 
Blocco3     -0.436 -0.057 -0.153 -0.002  0.546                                          
Data_rilv16 -0.331 -0.004  0.044 -0.003 -0.040 -0.039                                   
Data_rilv22 -0.329 -0.009  0.037 -0.016 -0.043 -0.040  0.551                            
Data_rilv29 -0.326 -0.003  0.039 -0.015 -0.041 -0.041  0.542  0.553                     
Data_rilv36 -0.317  0.004  0.047 -0.003 -0.041 -0.046  0.519  0.531  0.531              
Data_rilv52 -0.318  0.001  0.046 -0.010 -0.038 -0.036  0.525  0.536  0.540  0.518       
Data_riliv9 -0.324 -0.007  0.046 -0.007 -0.046 -0.044  0.539  0.546  0.536  0.515  0.520

Results show that two treatments ("Lavanda" and "Rosmarino") are significant, together with some sampling dates "Data_rilievo".
I then apply a post-hoc test as follows
> emmeans_trattamento <- emmeans(model1, ~ Trattamento)
> 
> # Esegue i confronti post-hoc tra i livelli del fattore Trattamento
> confronti_posthoc <- pairs(emmeans_trattamento)
> 
> # Visualizza i risultati dei confronti post-hoc
> summary(confronti_posthoc)
 contrast              estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Controllo - Lavanda     0.4325 0.191 Inf   2.263  0.1069
 Controllo - Rosmarino   0.4054 0.204 Inf   1.992  0.1911
 Controllo - Timo        0.2215 0.187 Inf   1.185  0.6362
 Lavanda - Rosmarino    -0.0271 0.205 Inf  -0.132  0.9992
 Lavanda - Timo         -0.2111 0.190 Inf  -1.110  0.6831
 Rosmarino - Timo       -0.1839 0.203 Inf  -0.907  0.8011

Results are averaged over the levels of: Blocco, Data_rilievo 
Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates

and significances have disappeared. Now the questions:

Why something that is significant in the glmer becomes not significant when performing pairwise comparisons in a post-hoc test?
How to interpret this result? I would tend to say that overall the two treatments are significant, but their effect is so small that is not observable during the pair-wise comparison. The second option is that no treatment is significant. Which one is the most correct interpretation?


The use of Tukey's method for comparisons could have been left out. 1 You could have considered a one sided test, because you are interested in an alternative hypothesis that the herbs have no effect as pesticide. 2 The Tukey's method is less sensitive/powerful when the range of variation is only for one group in a single direction (the control). See also the theory behind Tukey's HSD test

You could perform tests with 3 nested models. A first without effect, a second with a variable for treatment, a third with a variable for the specific treatment. Then for the comparison between the first and second case you will probably get a z.ratio around the average of -1.81 with a p-value around 0.035 or 0.07 depending on whether you consider a one sided or two sided test.

Thank you. Can I ask yuo more details on the code to allow comparison among the tests?
Which method can be used instead of Tukey?

you could use a likelihood ratio test comparing the three models. It might possibly be tricky due to the random intercepts. It is not exactly like the models are nested and the degrees of freedom are estimated. It will remain an approximation.

How many repetitions do you have within " ID_pianta"? It might possibly be not so logical to add it as a random effect if you only have a few measurements (and are these total counts or single Bernoulli 0/1 results?). The effects of the treatments will be dimmed by an overfitting with the random intercepts.

emmeans uses p-value adjustment for post-hoc comparisons by default (as you can see from the last line in emmeans output), whereas glmer summary does not. So, in your glmer output  your p-values are unadjusted for multiple comparisons. If you run
confronti_posthoc <- pairs(emmeans_trattamento, adjust="none")

you should get the same p-values as in the glmer output.
What you should do depends on your view on p-value adjustment and its relevance to your research design. Not adjusting increases the risk of type I errors (false positive results), but adjusting increases the risk of false negatives. One rough guideline is that if your study was more or less exploratory (i.e. you didn't have clear hypotheses prior to collecting the data), you probably need to do p-value adjustment. But many people do that even when they had clear hypotheses.
A compromise might be a more lenient version of p-value adjustment, such as Benjamini-Hochberg adjustment.

I tried and indeed I have got the same p-values as you said. I have also applied a contrast test and got the same results. I tried the Benjamini-Hochberg but I have "lost" the significances.
How can I justify this aspect (got significances in glmer and lost them during pairwise comparison)? Can I say that, overall there is an effect but it is not so marked to be observed during a post-hoc test?

There really is no absolute rule, you have to decide for yourself. I can say that if I had this data and I had been interested in all possible comparisons prior to collecting the data, I would adjust the p-values and hence the conclusion would be that there are no significant results. But I'm from a field where multiple testing without adjustment has caused a lot of harm (psychology). You are free to use unadjusted p-values and say the groups do differ. A colleague, editor, or a reviewer may complain about it and then you need to explain why you think p-value adjustment is not necessary here.

I would NOT say "overall there is an effect but it is not so marked to be observed during a post-hoc test". If you adjust the p-values, use the adjusted ones. If not, you don't need a sentence like this.

Also the significant effects in glmer output are not "overall" effects, they are also pairwise comparisons, but unadjusted ones.
